# "Browse With..." button missing in VS 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

I upgraded my MVC 3 project to MVC 4 according to the instructions here:
http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806

Everything works fine, except that I don't have the new Browse with.. button appearing in the toolbar, nor can I activate this option in the project's context menu.

I should note that the button appears properly in new MVC4 projects (i.e. those created from scratch instead of upgraded).

How can I fix this?

**Update:**
See workaround in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by creating a new .sln and adding my projects to it.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the top menu and add in the 'Standard' Toolbar.

If it's still not there you can right click -> Customize, select the 'Commands' tab. Select Toolbar: Standard then hit 'Reset All' (this will only reset the 'Standard' toolbar).

Answer (score 0):

Try just adding an '.aspx' web forms file to your project. You should get the 'Browse with ...' option in the context menu when right clicking on that file in the Solution Explorer. You should be able to change the browser that way. Then you can delete the '.aspx' file once you have chosen your browser. I have had to do this in the past.